# Alignment of tikz nodes fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-node

In what seems the simplest possible diagram ever the first node won't align to the left, and that's where I want it. I tried quite a lot, only if change the second node from `below left = of n1` to `below = of n1` the first node is on the left, but then the others will go to the right.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\listfiles
\documentclass[tikz,border=.5cm]{standalone}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{fixltx2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{activate={true,nocompatibility},%
  expansion=true,protrusion=true}{microtype}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.symbols,babel}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[style=german]{csquotes}
\usepackage{float, ragged2e, mathtools, unicode-math, letltxmacro, luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align = flush left}]
  \node (n1) {Bestehende Angst"|störung vor traumatischem
    Erlebnis};
  \node [below left = of n1] (n2) {Angststörung};
  \node [draw, starburst, right=of n2] (n3) {Trauma};
  \node [right = of n3] (n4) {Verstärkung der be-\\stehenden
    Angststörung};
  \node [below = of n2, distance = 4ex] (n5) {Angststörung};
  \node [draw, starburst, right = of n5] (n6) {Trauma};
  \node [right = of n6] (n7) {Angststörung \textbf{und} PTBS
    \hphantom{b}};
  \node [below = of n5.west] (n8) {};
  \node [below = of n7.east] (n9) {};
  \draw [thick, ->] (n2) to (n3);
  \draw [thick, ->] (n3) to (n4);
  \draw [thick, ->] (n5) to (n6);
  \draw [thick, ->] (n6) to (n7);
  \draw [thick, ->] (n8.east) to (n9.west) node [below left] {Zeit};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes]

Comment: Please clarify the desired output. What does "align to the left"  and "the others will go to the right"  mean in this context? Unrelated, but there is a `{` before `babel}`.

Comment: Do you mean you want ```\node [below = of n1.south west, anchor=north west] (n2) {Angststörung};``` (for the first Angststörung-node)?

Comment: Does `\node [below  = of n1.south west, anchor=west] (n2) {Angststörung};` give you the desired result?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., leandriis : Both changes work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following solution works for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.symbols,
                babel}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 9mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
     N/.style = {align=left, inner sep=0pt, on chain, join=by arr},
     S/.style = {starburst, draw, outer sep=1mm, on chain, join=by arr},
                        ] 
%
\node (n11) [N] {Angststörung};
\node (n12) [S] {Trauma};
\node (n13) [N] {Verstärkung der be-\\stehenden Angststörung};
%
\node (n21) [N,suspend join,
             below=of n11 |- n12.south] {Angststörung};
\node (n22) [S] {Trauma};
\node (n23) [N] {Angststörung \textbf{und} PTBS};
% titl
\node[above=of n12] {Bestehende Angstörung vor traumatischem Erlebnis};
% zeit 
\coordinate[below=of n21.west |- n22.south] (aux);
\draw [arr] 
    (aux) -- (aux-| n23.east) node [below left] {Zeit};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Summary: Use

```
\node [below = of n1.south west, anchor=north west] (n2) {Angststörung};
```

---

(Overly verbose explanation follows.) You have

```
 \node [below left = of n1] (n2) {Angststörung};
```

`below left` means that the top right corner of `n2` is placed at the bottom left corner of `n1`, with an offset in both x- and y-direction defined by `node distance`.

What you want to do is place the top left corner of `n2` directly below the bottom left corner of `n1`. So you first need

```
below = of n1.south west
```

You need to specify the `south west` anchor as otherwise it would be placed below the `south` anchor of `n1`.

Second you need to add

```
anchor = north west
```

*after* the `below` key. `below` will implicitly set `anchor=north`, and that setting has to be overridden. If you swap the order (`anchor=..., below=..`) the `anchor` setting won't have any effect.

Hence, `\node [below = of n1.south west, anchor=north west] (n2) {Angststörung};` gets you what you need.